# Allow to type values that are not in options

Tags: javascript, react-select

Basically, I have not find a way to setup select component to allow values that are not in the option set. I know that `select` suggests that it must be a selection. But I am looking to make it act more like an autocomplete. Any knowledge on that?

Comment: did you try AsyncSelect? if you didn't then import AsyncSelect from react-select. you can asynchronosly load and render it. https://react-select.com/home#async

Comment: You think there are no more simple options?

Comment: Could [creatable](https://react-select.com/creatable) be a solution ? so values not in option set would be added ?

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

import react-select

```
$ yarn add react-select@next

# or, using npm:
$ npm install react-select@next
```

The dropdown is searchable.

```
import React from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';

const tools = [
  { label: "Hammer", value: 1 },
  { label: "Hand Drill", value: 2 },
  { label: "Tape Rule", value: 3 },
  { label: "Saw", value: 4 },
  { label: "Ruler", value: 5 },
  { label: "Soldering Iron", value: 6 },
];

const App = () => (
  <div className="app">
    <div className="container">
      <Select options={tools} />
    </div>
  </div>
);
```